# Proof that $g(x) = f(x) || f(f(x))$ is a OWF when $f$ is a OWF

Tags: provable-security, one-way-function

Assume that $f$ is a one-way function (OWF), and let $\mathbin\|$ denote string concatenation.

Consider the function $g$ defined by $g(x) = f(x) \mathbin\| f(f(x))$. It is easy to prove that $g$ is a OWF as well, assuming that $f$ is length preserving (that is, $|f(x)|=|x|$ for all $x$). Here's a sample proof, taken from [Lindell's final exam](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/%7Elindell/89-856/solutions-moed-A-89-856-2005.ps):

[image: Lindell's proof]

Now consider the case where $f$ is a general OWF, not necessarily length preserving. This case is considered in [Katz & Lindell book, 2nd Edition](http://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Ejkatz/imc.html), Exercise 7.8:

[image: Exercise 7.8]

> **Q:** Why Lindell's proof for length-preserving $f$ does not work?
>
> **A:** In the proof mentioned above, $\mathcal{A}'$ invokes $\mathcal{A}$ on $y || f(y)$, which upon success, returns $x'$ such that $f(x') \mathbin\| f(f(x')) = y \mathbin\| f(y)$. However, this does not entail $f(x') = y$, as the length of $f(x')$ might be different from the length of $y$.

My question is, how to prove that that $g(x) = f(x) \mathbin\| f(f(x))$ is a OWF when $f$ is a **general** OWF?

Answer (score 3):

/!\ the counter-example I build below is not a formal refutation of the statement, a more rigorous analysis is needed, but it gives an intuition of why I think that $f'x\mapsto f(x)\mathbin\|f(f(x))$ is not necessarily an OWF (thanks to Christian Matt for pointing out the necessity of a more rigorous analysis).

It seems to me that $f': x \mapsto f(x)\mathbin\|f(f(x))$ is not necessarily a OWF when $f$ is not length-preserving. Consider the following function $f$:

- $h$ is an arbitrary length-preserving OWF. $g$ is an arbitrary OWF that compresses its input by a factor two.
- $f$ is defined as follows: on input $x$, if $|x|$ is odd, then $f(x) = 0^{|x|} \mathbin\| h(x)$. Else, if $|x|$ is even, then if $|x|/2$ is also even and $x$ is of the form $x' \mathbin\| 0^{3|x|/4}$, return $x' \mathbin\| 0^{|x|/4}$. Otherwise, if $x$ is of the form $x'' \mathbin\| 0^{|x|/2}$, return $h(x'')$. In all other cases, return $g(x)$.

So, as you can see, $f$ maps $n$-bit inputs to $n/2$-bit outputs when $n$ is even, and to $2n$-bit outputs when $n$ is odd. I think that one can prove that $f$ is indeed an OWF by picking an appropriate function $g$ whose image does not intersect with $\{0\}^n \times \{0,1\}^n$ so that on a random input $x$, the probability that $g(x)$ is of the form $x' \mathbin\| 0^{3|x|/4}$ is very small (as this is the "easy to invert" case).

Now, let $n \equiv 2 \bmod 4$ ($n$ is even, and $n/2$ is odd). Then when you receive $y = f(x)$ for a random $n$-bit input $x$, it is easy to invert $y \mathbin\| f(y)$: with very good probability, $x$ is not of the form $x'\mathbin\|0^{3|x|/4}$, hence $f(x) = g(x)$ (which is of odd length $n/2$). In this case it holds that $f(y) = 0^{n/2}\mathbin\|h(y)$. But this makes inverting $y \mathbin\| f(y)$ trivial:

$$y\mathbin\|f(y) = y\mathbin\|(0^{n/2}\mathbin\|h(y)) = (y\mathbin\|0^{n/2})\mathbin\|h(y) = f(y\mathbin\|0^{3n/2})\mathbin\|f(f(y||0^{3n/2}))$$

Hence one can simply return $y\mathbin\|0^{3n/2}$ to successfully invert $f':x \mapsto f(x)\mathbin\|f(f(x))$. So unless I'm missing something / making a mistake, $f': x \mapsto f(x)\mathbin\|f(f(x))$ is not necessarily a OWF when $f$ is not length-preserving.

EDIT: corrected mistakes in the previous version of my counter example.

Comment: I don't think it is so easy to show that your $f$ is one-way, even in the "obvious" case with odd $|x|$: One attempt to proving it is to give a reduction that inverts $h$. So, given $y = h(x)$, give $y' := 0^{|y|}||y$ to the algorithm $\mathcal{A}$ that inverts $f$. Now $x$ is a valid preimage that $\mathcal{A}$ *could* return, but $\mathcal{A}$ could also return some $x'$ with $f(x') = g(x') = y'$. In this case, you fail to invert $h$ and $g$ could actually be easy to invert for $g(x')$ of this form...

Comment: @ChristianMatt: you're right, I will have to look at it carefully, but I think something along the lines of what I proposed could be made to work, by using a more carefully crafted function $g$, one whose image does not intersect with $\{0\}^n \times \{0,1\}^n$. I edited my answer and will try to build a more formal counter example when I have more time.

Comment: I decided to donate the bounty to this ingenious answer, though as the OP points out, it needs a more careful analysis to prove that $g$ is actually NOT an OWF.